# Order by date in Sqlite where date is saved in text with format "EEE MM/dd/yy, h:mm a"

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, android-sqlite

I want to pick latest date from my table in android sqlite.
Date is saved in one of the column as 'text' with format "EEE MM/dd/yy, h:mm a"

Example:

Sun  11/15/15,  11:11 am

Mon  11/16/15, 5:00 pm

Mon  11/16/15, 4:00 pm

Mon  11/16/15,  4:31 pm

Mon  11/16/15,  4:29 pm

Mon  11/16/15,  4:16 pm

I am trying to use following code which is not working:

> SELECT (date_column) FROM test ORDER BY date(date_column) limit 1

Comment: date should be in format `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: why don't you store a timestamp in your table like any other built-in android provider do?

Answer (score 0):

Because the format you use "EEE MM/dd/yy, h:mm a" contain Mon,Sun etc. Order by doesn't work on those strings. So you can change the format to **"yyyyMMdd.HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"**, this should work.